# How do I replace an item in List(Of String) in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, list

I am having issues with one of my projects. In it, I am facing the obstacle of indexing problems. I have a list instantiated this way:

```
Public answers As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
```

Items are added to this list by this code:

```
Dim correctanswer As String = "" 'except the user changes the value with the GUI
frmMain.answers.Add(correctanswer)
```

(And by the way, I'm only including the relevant parts to this monster of a project, so I will post more code by request, if needed.)

This code works fine; however, I am attempting to allow the user to modify each list item at will. I tried doing that by the following method:

```
frmMain.answers.ElementAt(i) = correctanswer '(where 'i' is the index in question)
```

and the compiler doesn't like that. It's yelling at me.

> Expression is not a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment.

Now, I've faced this issue before when I was trying to replace items in a similar list; however, those items were my own custom classes. This is just a list of strings. I tried another method as well:

```
frmMain.RemoveAt(i)
frmMain.Insert(i, correctanswer)
```

The problem with that is, the order of the list gets mixed up. The indexes move around, and it ultimately makes a mess rather than doing what I want it to.

Can someone please give me a hand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`frmMain.answers(i) = correctanswer`

Here is a small example:

```
Dim answers As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
answers.Add("Answer A")
answers.Add("Answer B")
answers.Add("Answer C")
Dim correctanswer As String = ""

answers(1) = correctanswer
For Each str As String In answers
Console.WriteLine(str)
Next
```

This should print:

> Answer A
>
> Answer C

Comment: It should be `frmMain.answers(i)`, since this is VB.NET.

Comment: It depends on what frmMain is, and it's relationship to frmMain.  A guess would be that frmMain is the name of a form in the project and answers is part of the frmMain class.  If so it means that the OP is modifying the default instance.  If that is true then Pete is correct (or Me.answers).

Comment: frmMain is the main form, and answers is a list instantiated under frmMain. You are correct, @dbansnett.

Comment: +1 for using an enhanced for loop. Didn't know how to do that in VB.

Comment: @ChrisShula I believe he's talking about accessing frmMain properties from another form.

Comment: Do you mean variable? It's not a property of frmMain, it's just a list instantiated within the frmMain file.

Comment: @ChrisShula Variable/Property, doesn't matter.  Having some object instantiated in the main form and accessible through that form is a bad practice.  It's much better to work with some other non-ui object and you pass that around in your program.  Make sense?  His comment really has little to do with your question.  It's more of an architectural thing.

Comment: I understand what you're saying... Hm. My CS teacher never said that was bad. I guess I should probably use an external file. Thank you!